# PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'TABLES_UPDATE_DATA' denied

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am testing the Bigquery storage write API by attempting to write sample data into Bigquery and I am getting a permission error as below

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'TABLES_UPDATE_DATA' denied on resource 'projects/xxx/datasets/xxx.yyy/tables/xxx.yyy.test_customer_data' (or it may not exist).
```

I have given the service account the necessary roles according to this documentation. If I test the same service account using the Legacy streaming API I am able to write successfully into Bigquery. I will appreciate the help by being shown what might be wrong since we are intending to use the Bigquery storage write API. Thanks

Below is my full code, if it might help

```
"""
This code sample demonstrates how to write records in pending mode
using the low-level generated client for Python.
"""
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1
from google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1 import types
from google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1 import writer
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import customer_record_pb2  #

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'xxx-b033d9535e9d.json' #The Json file is the same location

storage_client = storage.Client()


def create_row_data(row_num: int, name: str):
    row = customer_record_pb2.CustomerRecord()
    row.row_num = row_num
    row.customer_name = name
    return row.SerializeToString()


def append_rows_pending(project_id: str, dataset_id: str, table_id: str):
    """Create a write stream, write some sample data, and commit the stream."""
    write_client = bigquery_storage_v1.BigQueryWriteClient()
    parent = write_client.table_path(project_id, dataset_id, table_id)
    write_stream = types.WriteStream()

    # Setting the Pending Mode
    write_stream.type_ = types.WriteStream.Type.PENDING
    write_stream = write_client.create_write_stream(
    parent=parent, write_stream=write_stream
    )
    stream_name = write_stream.name
    request_template = types.AppendRowsRequest()
    request_template.write_stream = stream_name
    proto_schema = types.ProtoSchema()
    proto_descriptor = descriptor_pb2.DescriptorProto()
    customer_record_pb2.CustomerRecord.DESCRIPTOR.CopyToProto(proto_descriptor)
    proto_schema.proto_descriptor = proto_descriptor
    proto_data = types.AppendRowsRequest.ProtoData()
    proto_data.writer_schema = proto_schema
    request_template.proto_rows = proto_data

    # AppendRowsStream to send an arbitrary number of requests to a stream.
    append_rows_stream = writer.AppendRowsStream(write_client, request_template)

    # First Batch
    proto_rows = types.ProtoRows()
    proto_rows.serialized_rows.append(create_row_data(1, "Alice"))
    proto_rows.serialized_rows.append(create_row_data(2, "Bob"))

    request = types.AppendRowsRequest()
    request.offset = 0
    proto_data = types.AppendRowsRequest.ProtoData()
    proto_data.rows = proto_rows
    request.proto_rows = proto_data

    response_future_1 = append_rows_stream.send(request)

    # Sending another batch.
    proto_rows = types.ProtoRows()
    proto_rows.serialized_rows.append(create_row_data(3, "Charles"))
    request = types.AppendRowsRequest()
    proto_data = types.AppendRowsRequest.ProtoData()
    proto_data.rows = proto_rows
    request.proto_rows = proto_data
    request.offset = 2
    response_future_2 = append_rows_stream.send(request)
    print(response_future_1.result())
    print(response_future_2.result())

    # Shutdown background threads and close the streaming connection.
    append_rows_stream.close()
    write_client.finalize_write_stream(name=write_stream.name)

    # Commit the stream you created earlier.
    batch_commit_write_streams_request = types.BatchCommitWriteStreamsRequest()
    batch_commit_write_streams_request.parent = parent
    batch_commit_write_streams_request.write_streams = [write_stream.name]
    write_client.batch_commit_write_streams(batch_commit_write_streams_request)

    print(f"Writes to stream: '{write_stream.name}' have been committed.")


append_rows_pending(project_id='xxxx', dataset_id='xxxx.yyyy',
                    table_id='xxxx.yyyy.test_customer_data')
```

Comment: What's the permission that you granted?

Comment: thanks for the question @guillaumeblaquiere.The following are the roles that I gave the service account  BigQuery Admin,BigQuery Data Editor and BigQuery Data Owner

Comment: Do you change the schema or only write the data?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by changing the schema but am just following this [GCP doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#write_data_using_the_python_client) since am learning and testing the solution at this stage. I believe I am just writing data?

Comment: @oyugi.collins were you able to move forward with this. Also trying to use Bigquery Storage API but could not find some boilerplate code in python to use (except for this question :D ).

Comment: @Urvah Shabbir yes I was able to move forward. What worked for me was I changed the way I was referencing the table, from using the dot as a separator to using the actual names without the dataset or project ids for example instead of dataset_id='xxxx.yyyy', table_id='xxxx.yyyy.test_customer_data'. I used dataset_id='xxxx and  table_id='test_customer_data'. Let me know if this will work for you for me to update the question with an answer